# Difference between @Autowired MockMvc and webAppContextSetup in spring test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-test

There are two ways to instantiate `MockMvc` in spring's test: by `@Autowired` or by `webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();`

In spring's [getting started guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/):

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(GreetingController.class)
public class WebMockTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    // ...

    @Test
    public void greetingShouldReturnMessageFromService() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/greeting")).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

And in spring's [tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/):

```
@Before
public void setup() throws Exception {
    this.mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
    // ...
}
```

One observation I have is, when `spring-security` is in class path, the two mockMvc behaves differently. With `spring-security` in classpath, all HTTP endpoints are secured with Basic Auth as stated in the [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-security.html).

I would expect the test

`this.mockMvc.perform(get("/greeting")).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk());`

to fail with HTTP 401 as no credentials were provided.
It is the case for `@Autowired`

```
MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 401
    Error message = Full authentication is required to access this resource
          Headers = {X-Content-Type-Options=[nosniff], X-XSS-Protection=[1; mode=block], Cache-Control=[no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate], Pragma=[no-cache], Expires=[0], X-Frame-Options=[DENY], Strict-Transport-Security=[max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains], WWW-Authenticate=[Basic realm="Spring"]}
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
```

But tests still pass with `mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(...).build()` version

What are their difference(s) and when to use which?

Comment: you need additional Security initialization :    `mvc = MockMvcBuilders    .webAppContextSetup(context).apply(SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity()).build();`

Comment: Wondering if you managed to get an explanation for this? I faced similar behavior and wasted quite a bit of my time.

Comment: Any answer found on the core question, which way to use?